# nw_read_request_report [C9] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, appdelegate, url-scheme

I got this error with application connection lost. While redirecting from another app to my app I face this issue.This issue triggered only on live app, getting error with connection lost and while debugging with Xcode getting error but redirected to specific view controller successfully   I used deep linking with url scheme for handling response from another app. Still not getting clarity to what exact issue is there because not able to debug live app issue. 
Working on iOS 13.2
In AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    let components = NSURLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)
    let params = components?.queryItems
    signedResponse = (params?.first(where:{$0.name == "signedResponse"})?.value)!

    self.decodedMsgString = String(data:Data(base64Encoded: signedResponse)!,encoding:.utf8)!

    print("decodedMsgString : \(decodedMsgString)")


    //Call API here

    return true

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also ran into this issue, maybe this could give you an insight?
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106838

From one of the replies

> Following up, we determined that the issue was caused because our app continued to issue new NSURLConnection requests after going into the background and wasn't explicitly making them background tasks. As we didn't need background syncing, putting in code to prevent new requests from going out once the app was in the background eliminated this error.

Answer (score 1):

There was the same problem, after returning to the application, it was necessary to make a short pause before requesting data from the deep link.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
           YourNetworkResponse
    }
```